# What are the rgb values of C++ colored console text?

Tags: colors

I remember in my old days in C++ I used SetConsoleTextAttribute to change the color of the text in the console window. What are the rbg values of those 16 colors? I want to put them into Gimp to make an index mode to convert an image to C++ colors.

Answer (score 3):

There are no "C++ colors", there are *console* colors.

The 16-color palette of Windows Console is adjustable (via window menu → Properties → Color). However, **its default colors use values 0, 128, or 255 for R/G/B,** with the exception of light gray (192, 192, 192):

- black (0, 0, 0)
- dark blue (0, 0, 128)
- dark green (0, 128, 0)
- dark cyan (0, 128, 128)
- dark red (128, 0, 0)
- dark purple (128, 0, 128)
- dark brown (128, 128, 0)
- light gray (192, 192, 192)
- dark gray (128, 128, 128)
- light blue (0, 0, 255)
- light green (0, 255, 0)
- ...

I believe the color palette order matches the [CGA palette order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_8-bit_computer_hardware_palettes#CGA).